# Thunar/PCManFm/Nautilus freeze 25 seconds at startup

Tags: kali-linux, freeze, thunar

I'm on Kali Linux with everything up-to-date.

It freezes 25 seconds whe lauch Thunar/PCManFm/Nautilus or other file manager based on GTK. It doesn't happen when PC is just booted on, it start happening after being used for a while, maybe half hour, maybe 24 hours later.

**EDIT: Workaround**

`killall gvfsd-trash` fixes the problem temporary, if it still freezes, try `killall gvfsd`.

**EDIT 2: Fixed**

It seems that the bug was fixed in recent updates, it has been working all fine for about 2 months, try a system update if it still happens.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem on Manjaro. Workaround helps. Thanks!